# Mint vs Secondary market NFT prices

Tags: dapps, nft, opensea

I am releasing an NFT project art collection with an influencer with 10 000 nfts.
Please tell me how should I improve my strategy:
I plan to mint 5000 and list them on opensea from a "deployer wallet".
I will list the basic traits at 5 usd, rare traits for 15 usd, I will create a minting website for the community for the other 5000 and my asking is what should be the minting price?
I am thinking about 6 usd, but do you think 4 usd is a better choice?
Or maybe 7 usd?
*all prices are in usd for simplicity but the collection will be on polygon matic. Thanks a lot in advance.*